Load draws more current that power supply provides
I have a power supply that pushes a maximum of 30V and 5 amps. If I push 30V through a load that has a resistance of 3 ohms, the load would then be drawing 10A, right? 30/3 = 10. (Ohms Law). This is more than what the power supply can supply. So what would happen?

it is current that gets pushed thtough a load, not voltage ... a power supply generates voltage ... it that voltage that does the pushing of current through a load

Nothing good! You cannot get 300W from a supply that has a max 150W. Depending on the supply, 150W continuous may be a problem.  Given the info provided, we csnnot answer your question.

That depends on the supply.
Some supplies will limit the current by cutting the voltage back. Some will have an over-current circuit that will trip, cutting off the output, and need to be reset. Some will have a fuse that should blow, and some will just burn up or fail in some similar way.

The power supply cannot change the resistance and is limited by its maximum output current of 5A.
So the output voltage must decrease to 15V.

You should consult the datasheet / manual for the power supply you are using. That being said a practical / realizable power supply will typically "current limit" which means it will output the maximum possible current, and lower the output voltage as much as necessary to do that.

What would happen would depend on the specific power supply.
Some supplies will just drop the output voltage until the current is the max (5 A in this case, which would mean the output voltage would drop to 15 V).
Some supplies will trip an overcurrent protection circuit and latch off (perhaps until power is cycled, or a reset line is toggled).
Some supplies may latch off for a period and re-try.  If the overload is gone it will resume normal operation.  If not, it will latch off again.  (This is called "hiccup mode".)
And some supplies (though hopefully a very small percentage) will fail.  I tested hundreds of supplies for a qualification exercise years ago, and failure, especially at higher ambient temperature, was surprisingly common. Though to be fair, these were AC adapter "bricks" not lab supplies. A good lab supply would almost never fail under these conditions.
